# spring security how to set defaultFailureUrl from custom filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have my custom filter :

```
@Component("MyAuthFilter")
public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private int errCode = 0;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        System.out.println("running my own version of UsernmePasswordFilter ... ");

        String login = (String) request.getParameter("login");
        String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
        errCode = validate(login, password);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password);
        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    private int validate(String login, String password) {

        if (login.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
            return 4;
        }
        if (login.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            return 2;
        }
        if (!login.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
            return 3;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

this is my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/courses"
            authentication-failure-url="/login"
            username-parameter="loginField"
            password-parameter="passwordField" 
            />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="ars" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

i want to set DefaultFailureUrl to ("/login?error=" + errCode);
how can i do this from my filter?
If i'm trying to do something like

```
@Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler getFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=" + errCode);
        return handler;
    }
```

it shows an error that  AuthenticationFailureHandler doesn't found. I just want to use default spring security Failure handler and just change its url.

Comment: What is the url that you want to redirect to?

Comment: OK try this way and it is working  I add                                            authentication-failure-url="/somewhere?error=true"

Comment: i need to set a number after error=_  ,so i want to change DefaultFailureUrl  and not to use custom in xml

Comment: try /somewhere?error=45667 and dont use your been,  number can be retrieved by using ${param.error}

Comment: the number should be set dinamically from my filter, not constant from xml.